# c# Удалить повторяющееся элементы из списка

Tags: c#, linq

Как оказалось метод Distinct не работает когда мы хотим убрать одинаковые сложные элементы из списка

```
 public class User
    {
    public User(string name, string surname)
        {
            Name = name;
            Surname = surname;
        }
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
    }
public static List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
UserList.Add(new User("Ivan","Ivanov"));
UserList.Add(new User("Ivan", "Andreev"));
UserList.Add(new User("Ivan", "Ivanov"));
UserList.Add(new User("Ivan", "Ivanov"));
var u = UserList.Distinct();
```

Все равно получается 4 элемента. Как поступить? Может есть способ это решить через LINQ?

Comment: Для не стандартных объектов нужно переопределять Equals и GetHashCode, как к примеру показано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601805/6808809), либо использовать класс с реализованным `IEqualityComparer` интерфейсом.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class UserComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
  public bool Equals(User x, User y)
  {
    return x.Name == y.Name && x.Surname == y.Surname;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(User x)
  {
    return (x.Name + "_" + x.Surname).GetHashCode();
  }
}

var u = UserList.Distinct(new UserComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

Переопределите методы Equals и GetHashCode для вашего класса, тогда метод Dinstinct должен заработать.